# Hashtags for posts with swift using parse

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a `uitextfield` for tags. My Parse `"Post"` Class has a column for the tags when the user is creating the posts. I want the textfield for tags to be saved to the data base in such a way that I can query that column in the Posts class and also be able to show them in the app separated with "#" right after the keyboard is dismissed or when they hit the space bar.

Basically the same functionality as stack overflows tags when creating this question, but for ios!

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: I dont understand how to do this in swift, as ive never done this feature before and having trouble formulating a strategy or logic behind it

Comment: Are you stuck with a column which is an array of strings for tags? You also need to deal with the data store and query and then, as a separate question, anything about displaying the data

Comment: I am stuck on everything. Imagine a text field that u type in words. those words are whats displayed in the tags column. now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags should really be a class, and your column of tags should be an array of pointers (not strings).

As the user types you can query for the matching tags and display these options. If no match is found you can create and save a new tag. Then add the tag to the array of pointers (add unique method).

When querying for your objects you can use the includes key option to have the array of tag pointers downloaded at the same time so you have the tag names to display.

To query by tag you get the tag object and then query for objects where the tags array contains that tag object.

Comment: Thank you! I like this approach, will try implementation this weekend. Can I follow up if I have anymore questions?

Comment: Sure, though it's best to raise a new question describing the specific issue you have